# (How) can one use the concept of apparent depth to solve this ray-refraction problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction

I was solving the following question:

> An observer can see through a small hole on the side of a jar (radius 15 cm) at a point at height of 15 cm from the bottom (see figure). The hole is at a height of 45 cm. When the jar is filled with a liquid up to a height of 30 cm the same observer can see the edge at the bottom of the jar. If the refractive index of the liquid is N/100, the value of N is
>
> [image]

So one way to solve this is by Snell's law of course which gives $100(\sqrt{\frac52})$ (the correct answer) but I was wondering if I could use the concept of apparent depth as it seems to have shifted 15 cm (as the observer can now see the bottom at the same point the top of the jar was) but then I get 200 as the answer. Can anyone explain why I cannot use the apparent depth method?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128663/discussion-on-question-by-ayush-kshitij-how-can-one-use-the-concept-of-apparen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  method  of apparent depth approximation is not valid here since the angles of the incident and refracted rays are not small.

To the contrary, using the Figure-01 below you have the exact solution in one stroke. Note that the result is independent of the length $\,a$.

[image]