# It's about the apparent position of anything in case of refraction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reflection, refraction

So my question is that,what actually the apparent position of let's say a coin in water seen by us is??
It's a small experiment in textbooks that take a coin in a shallow and wider bowl and mark the position from where you are not able to the coin. And then put water in the bowl upto neck and then go back to that position from where you were not able to see that coin,you will find that after putting water in Bowl you are able to see the coin which was not seen without water from the position that you have marked earlier.
So here it is said that it's the apparent position of coin that we see after filling water.
Ok let's assume that it is the apparent position but what that apparent position actually is??
Is that apparent position image of coin??
If that is image of the coin then how we are able to see that image because we always take water surface as a plane mirror.Then how image of coin inside the water surface is seen by person at outside the water surface??

Comment: Related : [How can one use the concept of apparent depth to solve this ray-refraction problem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/659615/).